# Deseriaize Json from WebAPI using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the following Json format returned from a WebAPI. Can you guys help to deserialize please?.

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://....... ","value":[
    **{
      "RecordNumber":"LDxxxx","RecordType":"Loan","PropertyAddress":{ "Address1":"601 xxxx","Address2":null,"Zip":"99999","City":"abc","State":"ab","County":"abcd" }
        ,"Summary":{ "BorrowerName":null,"ProductCode":null,"Status":"Not Registered" }
    }**,{
            "RecordNumber":"LDxxxx","RecordType":"Loan","PropertyAddress":{ "Address1":"601 xxxx","Address2":null,"Zip":"99999","City":"abc","State":"ab","County":"abcd" }
        ,"Summary":{ "BorrowerName":null,"ProductCode":null,"Status":"Not Registered" }
      },
….]
 }
```

I need what's in the **value** element. The bold is what is repeated in the return from API. I created a class that matches the description as below.

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RecordNumber")]
    public string RecordNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RecordType")]
    public string RecordType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PropertyAddress")]
    public PropertyAddress PropertyAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Summary")]
    public Summary Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Was able to skip the first record in the Json array using the following, got the "Value" part....but have not been successful in retrieving the "Value" object

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(forecast);
foreach (var kv in dict.Skip(1))
{
     JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(kv.Value.ToString());
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Satya

Comment: Is that really the exact JSON?  With the `**` and all?

Comment: Maccettura...no, I put those in there, just to indicate a repetition of the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize to concrete classes (with the help of http://json2csharp.com/)

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SOTest.Result>(json);
```

---

```
public class SOTest
{
    public class PropertyAddress
    {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public object Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
    }

    public class Summary
    {
        public object BorrowerName { get; set; }
        public object ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string RecordNumber { get; set; }
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public PropertyAddress PropertyAddress { get; set; }
        public Summary Summary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
        public string Context { get; set; }
        public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```